# Remapping keyboard accent shortcuts

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard

I have a "UK-English International Macintosh" keyboard, and I use the accent shortcuts quite heavily since I'm French (AZERTY is terrible for programming).

Like <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> for ´, <kbd>option</kbd>+` for ``, etc

Is there a way to make Emacs completely ignore the command key, and change the meta key to something other than option ? (pretty much every key has an additional character when used with option)

I can't really use it like this, those shortcuts are too important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the following two user settings. I think you want at least
`ns-alternate-modifier` `none`.

```
ns-alternate-modifier is a variable defined in `C source code'.

Its value is `super'
Original value was `meta'

This variable describes the behavior of the alternate or option key.
Either SYMBOL, describing the behavior for any event,
or (:ordinary SYMBOL :function SYMBOL :mouse SYMBOL), describing behavior
separately for ordinary keys, function keys, and mouse events.

Each SYMBOL is `control', `meta', `alt', `super', `hyper' or `none'.
If `none', the key is ignored by Emacs and retains its standard meaning.
```

And:

```
ns-command-modifier is a variable defined in `C source code'.

Its value is `control'
Original value was `super'

This variable describes the behavior of the command key.
Either SYMBOL, describing the behavior for any event,
or (:ordinary SYMBOL :function SYMBOL :mouse SYMBOL), describing behavior
separately for ordinary keys, function keys, and mouse events.

Each SYMBOL is `control', `meta', `alt', `super', `hyper' or `none'.
If `none', the key is ignored by Emacs and retains its standard meaning.
```

(there's also `ns-control-modifier` and `ns-right-*` variants if you
only want to affect the key on the right hand side of the keyboard, and all of them have aliases starting with `mac-` instead of `ns-`)

Comment: Upvoted, will try once I'm back home and accept if this solves the problem (which I think it likely will).

Comment: Accepting with one caveat : Those variables have aliases that I think are more helpful, namely `mac-option-modifier` and `mac-command-modifier`. 

I ended up using `(setq mac-right-option-modifier 'none')` so that my right option key can be used for accenting, and my left option key for emacs's `meta` key.